# getting 404 error on some wordpress subdirectory sites

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I have wordpress multisite set up on Server 2012/IIS 8 using subdirectories rather than subdomains for  each site.

I have set up 6 sites but 4 of them give 404 when I attempt to bring up the dashboard (/wp-admin/) or visit the site

I thought maybe some of the sites had somehow gotten corrupted so I created a new site but it gives a 404 as well.

I cannot see any obvious difference between the sites that work and those that don't.

The only clue I have is that the 404 requests don't even show up in the IIS log.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered what is going wrong but not why.   The sites run on an internal url http:localhost:8100.  On the newly created site when I  go to edit page it was showing http://localhost/.  This is why it was not showing up in the IIS logs.

Unfortunately, If I try to change it, it just reverts.   The working sites all show http://localhost:8100/   If I change siteurl  and home under settings for the non-working site they also just revert back.   So I've discovered the 404 problem but don't yet have a solution